# Jersey reading only first @QueryParam out of @BeanParam parameters

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have this Jersey POST resource :

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response blablabla(InputStream inputStream, 
@BeanParam ImportParams importParams) throws IOException, JAXBException, SAXException {
```

Here is the ImportParams class :

```
public class ImportParams {
    @QueryParam(value = "importType")
    public ImportType importType = ImportType.MERGE;

    @ApiParam("Force stop point type for all stop points in file. Useful if no modality defined in the netex file.")
    @QueryParam(value = "forceStopType")
    public StopTypeEnumeration forceStopType;

}
```

When I use curl to post to the the resource, only the first query parameter I specify after the question mark in the URL is read by jersey :

```
curl -XPOST -H"Content-Type: application/xml" -H"authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -d@$3  http://localhost:8585/services/stop_places/netex?forceStopType=TRAM_STATION&importType=MERGE

==> forceStopType has the right value, and importType is null

curl -XPOST -H"Content-Type: application/xml" -H"authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -d@$3  http://localhost:8585/services/stop_places/netex?importType=MERGE&forceStopType=TRAM_STATION

==> importType has the right value and forceStopType is null
```

I've used @BeanParam many times before and it used to work, so I must be missing something obvious.... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha found out - stupid me. Had to put double quotes around the URL when cURLing :

```
curl -XPOST -H"Content-Type: application/xml" -H"authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -d@$3  "http://localhost:8585/services/stop_places/netex?forceStopType=TRAM_STATION&importType=MERGE"
```